# Sobel operator 'Edges' function results in an all-white image

Tags: c, cs50, sobel

I think I've made it somewhat right, but it doesn't seem to work properly. Maybe it went wrong for the edges of picture of something else, I have no clue where the problem is.

It's nearly workable, just getting all-white image, problem somewhere in linking pixels with Gx/Gy arrays.

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92JUL.png)

[Real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuJUQ.png)

[Definition of Sobel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZs7D.png)

```
// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Grid 3x3 then every Color * Gy * Gx, new color = G (sqrt(Gx^2 + Gy^2))
   int Gx[3][3] = {{1,0,-1},{2,0,-2},{1,0,-1}};
   int Gy[3][3] = {{1,2,1},{0,0,0},{-1,-2,-1}};
   RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width]; //temp array

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)  //copy to temporary array
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) //going through array of pixels
        {
            signed int RedX = 0, GreenX = 0, BlueX = 0, RedY = 0, GreenY = 0, BlueY =0; //average color value = 0
            unsigned int TempG = 0;
            for (int k = (i - 1); k <= i + 1; k++) //boundaries of Sobel (3x3)
            {
                for( int l = (j - 1); l <= j + 1; l++) //boundaries
                {
                    if (k >= 0 && k <= (height - 1) && l >= 0 && l <= (width - 1)) //checking if pixel exists
                    {
                        RedX += (temp[k][l].rgbtRed * Gx[k - i][l - j]);  //Calculating value in X direction
                        GreenX += (temp[k][l].rgbtGreen * Gx[k - i][l - j]);
                        BlueX += (temp[k][l].rgbtBlue *  Gx[k - i][l - j]);
//problem here
                        RedY += (temp[k][l].rgbtRed * Gy[k - i][l - j]); // In Y direction
                        GreenY += (temp[k][l].rgbtGreen * Gy[k - i][l - j]);
                        BlueY += (temp[k][l].rgbtBlue *  Gy[k - i][l - j]);
                    }
                }
            }

         TempG = round (sqrt (pow (RedX, 2) + pow (RedY, 2))); //G = SquareRoot(Gx^2 + Gy^2)
         if (TempG > 255)
         {
            TempG = 255; //limiting color value
         }
         image[i][j].rgbtRed = TempG; //assigning


         TempG = round (sqrt (pow (GreenX, 2) + pow (GreenY, 2)));
          if (TempG > 255)
         {
            TempG = 255;
         }
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = TempG;

         TempG = round (sqrt (pow (BlueX, 2) + pow (BlueY, 2)));
        if (TempG > 255)
         {
            TempG = 255;
         }
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = TempG;
        }
    }
   return;
}
```

Comment: `(int i = 0; i <= height;` Use `<`, not `<=`... Stepping out of bounds... Same for the inner `j` loop... And for the inner loops, too... Go read about C's array indexing (from '0' to 'N-1').

Comment: Look closer: `Gx[k][l]` What are the valid ranges of your arrays? What are the ranges of `k` and `l`? If you do not see it from the code, run your program in a debugger and step through the code, watching your variable contents.

Comment: @Fe2O3 The 2 inner most loops are correct. The index is supposed to go from `-1` .. `+1`. But I would suggest to not include `i` and `j` as offset there.

Comment: @Gerhardh yup, thanks, that was really stupid of me, but how do I then link pixels with matrix of Gx and Gy? I'm very much newbie, sorry for stupid questions :(
Do I need like make Gx the size of [height][width] and fill it with these numbers I have? Like fill with same blocks of this Gx/Gy Matrix?

Comment: @Gerhardh Take a closer look at the `<=` and `<` being used in the inner loop with its `l` (el) counter...

Comment: @webmessiah Regarding the dainty "copying" of each element at the top of the function. The C library offers a function called `memcpy()` that could replace those two loops and 3 lines of assignment. It pays to learn and use proven Standard Library functions whenever possible.

Comment: You can either use `Gx[k-i][l-j]` or make `k` and `l` only run from -1 to +1 and use it like this: `temp[i+k][j+l].rgbtRed * Gx[k][l];`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Ah, I missed that one for `l`. There it should be `<=` as well. Only the loop with `k` is correct.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I've tried different combinations (with = and without both for K and L) it has affected the result, but just added a small triangle of strangle noise in right bottom corner

Comment: @Gerhardh I've applied suggested method `Gx[k - i][l - j]`, it didn't help much, but we're definetely going somewhere [NewResult](https://ibb.co/HHqndHQ)

Comment: @webmessiah Each value of the RGB should fall in the range of 0-255... I don't know the assignment, but it _feels_ like the code needs to sum the 4, 6 or 9 pixel values (for each colour), then divide by the number of pixels summed before the Sobel magic is applied... Have a think about what value would result from summing 9 "red" pixels, multiplying and squaring... It seems to me there's a step missing...

Comment: I think, Fe203 is on the right track. But it is probably just an overflow. You might add If you add some pixel multiplied by 2, you could get above 255. Just limit it to 255 per color.

Comment: @Gerhardh A common SO question comes from some CS50 assignment about "blurring an image." Common to those calculations is summing the R or G or B values from 3, 5 or 8 adjoining pixels and the central pixel itself (into an `int`), then finding the _average_ intensity and assigning that to the copy being filled. This "average" will always be between 0 and 255... "Sobel multiplying" needs to be applied correctly.

Comment: @Gerhardh applied all of suggested changes (except of `memcpy()`) still geting noise instead of picture, you can see changes in edited code above.

Comment: @Fe2O3 i'm currently doing the Lab from CS50, did blur correctly, this task is next in the same 'problem set'

Comment: @Fe2O3 I know the blur task but I think, edge detection is not about averaging as that would rather completely defeat the specific weighting of the pixels.

Comment: Hint: Of course you must do that chopping at 255 with an integer type larger than 8 bits, i.e. before appliying to the values within the `RGBTRIPLE `struct.

Comment: @Gerhardh Fair enough, and I think you're right!!!... It's late here, and I've already typed more than I should regarding this question. Just making suggestions...

Comment: @Gerhardh you mean I must first check wether it's bigger than 255? like that: 
````
    if (round (sqrt (pow (RedX, 2) + pow (RedY, 2)) / count) > 255)
         {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
         }
         else
         {
           image[i][j].rgbtRed = round (sqrt (pow (RedX, 2) + pow (RedY, 2)) / count); //G 
    = SquareRoot(Gx^2 + Gy^2)
         }
``` ?

Comment: No, not like this. Use a temp variable `unsigned int  TempG = round(...); if (TempG > 255) TempG = 255;` Then assign this variable to your pixel data. Same for R and B as well. And don't do `/ count`. There is no averaging involved for edge detection

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion above was incorrect. `Gy[k - i][l - j]);` This is off by 1. As `k` starts at `i-1`, `k-i` will start at `-1` which is obviously invalid as an index for your arrays. You need to add `+1` for all your access to `Gx` and `Gy`. Same for `l`. As mentioned above: Try to run your program in a debugger and watch variables carefully while stepping through the code.

Comment: @Gerhardh you really helped me a lot, is there any way to thank you? (everything is working now as it supposed to)

Comment: If you want to show the solution, post an answer and possibly mark it as accepted!

Comment: @mkrieger1 yup, sorry, I'm new to this forum, thanks for advice :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED WITH: As I made a loop for `(k = (i - 1))` and `for (l = (j - 1))` and went through **Gx** and **Gy** using same variable it started with value of **-1**, the variable **RedX** (for example) has been taking a value of element of **Gx with index -1** i.e. `Gx[-1][-1]`. That is very stupid mistake, but it is what it is, so to solve this I've changed the index by which we call **Gx** and **Gy** elements: `RedX = Gx[k - i + 1][l - j + 1]`. Very appreciate a **@Gerhardh** help with that one, you're an angel :3.
[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o2v5.png)